# MariaDB - How to find the non english characters/words

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3, mariadb-10.5

Here we have the "name" column and values are
"Kumaran",
"Poziom insuliny",
"surowicy",
"Alphabets".

The above values "Poziom insuliny",
"surowicy" - are not an english words.
Can you tell me how to find those words in mariaDB.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need a dictionnary that contains all English words, and then, you can compare

Comment: How to get the dictionary in the mariadb?